# How to exclude sidebar from pages?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to exclude sidebar from pages? I put some page id's in exclude page in appearance -> widget -> pages -> left sidebar. But these pages still exist in sidebar which is not to.

[Link to site](http://goo.gl/ek63ye)

Here's the code of left sidebar

```
 <?php 
 global $post, $accesspress_ray_options;
 $accesspress_ray_settings = get_option( 'accesspress_ray_options',    $accesspress_ray_options );
if(is_front_page()){
$post_id = get_option('page_on_front');
}else{
$post_id = $post->ID;
}
$post_class = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'accesspress_ray_sidebar_layout', true );

if($post_class=='left-sidebar' || $post_class=='both-sidebar' ){
?>
<div id="secondary-left" class="widget-area left-sidebar sidebar">
    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ) ) : ?>
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- #secondary -->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: appearance > widget > pages > sidebar is not a default option in Wordpress, indicating it's provided by your theme. What theme are you using?

Comment: I'm using accesspress ray @Ohgodwhy

Comment: Judging by the function names: http://accesspressthemes.com/accesspress-ray/

Comment: @rnevius that's the theme, im using right now

Comment: There's nothing in the code above that mentions anything about excluding sidebars...

Comment: I think so. So what is the right code, can you give it pls @rnevius ?

Answer (score 0):

The right approach at this would be to create custom page templates. So that you can have page templates with sidebar and without sidebar.

[Read more about it here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)

You can entirely copy your **page.php** and define the following to it.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: No Sidebar Page Template
*/
```

And make sure you don't have the **get_sidebar()** in the new template.